# How to Store stock ticker updates as daily weekly monthly etc

Tags: java, postgresql, datetime

I have a need to backup stock data into "day", "past seven days", "1 month", "3 months" and "5 years" tables. whats the best way in doing this. Storing the current data real time in one table and moving it into these tables accordingly at the end of the day at a certain time, is the initiative I have taken. Data are symbol, trade price, date

Answer (score 0):

I'd use a master table with all the data, then *materialized views* for each chunk, and I'd update the materialized views from the master table daily.

Here a "materialized view" can just be another table that you `TRUNCATE` then `INSERT INTO ... SELECT` to populate. Or you can be  a bit trickier and do a partial `DELETE` followed by a partial `INSERT INTO ... SELECT` of only the new data.

It's not really clear why you need this in the first place though. Views are often quite sufficient.